# Where condition when joining to a table twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have a Bug class with analysts and committers, who are in the users table.

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :analyst, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :committer, class_name: 'User'
  ...
end
```

I have a search which can include searching for analyst, committer, or both.

How do I know what table alias active record will use for my table?

---

The SQL I get if I search for analyst like so,

```
analyst = 'abenge'
Bug.joins(:analyst).where(users: {username: analyst}).to_sql
=> "SELECT `bugs`.* FROM `bugs`
    INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `bugs`.`analyst_id`
    WHERE `users`.`username` = 'abenge'"
```

Likewise the SQL I get if I search for committer,

```
analyst = 'amcdonnell'
Bug.joins(:committer).where(users: {username: committer}).to_sql
=> "SELECT `bugs`.* FROM `bugs`
    INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `bugs`.`committer_id`
    WHERE `users`.`username` = 'amcdonnell'"
```

But if I search for both, the where call cannot use `users` for both.  The table gets aliased, and I need to use the alias.

```
Bug.joins(:analyst, :committer)
   .where(users: {username: committer})
   .where(committers_bugs: {username: committer}).to_sql
=> "SELECT `bugs`.* FROM `bugs`
    INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `bugs`.`analyst_id`
    INNER JOIN `users` `committers_bugs` ON `committers_bugs`.`id` = `bugs`.`committer_id`
    WHERE `users`.`username` = 'abenge'
      AND `committers_bugs`.`cvs_username` = 'amcdonnell'"
```

So my question is, "How do I know which key to use in my where clause for the committer's username, when in one case it is `users` and in the other case it is `committers_bugs`?

---

I want the code to be something like this:

```
relation = Bug

analyst = params['analyst']
if analyst.present?
  relation = relation.joins(:analyst).where(user: {username: analyst})
end

committer = params['committer']
if committer.present?
  relation = relation.joins(:committer).where(committers_bugs: {username: committer})
end
```

The problem is that the above works if they search for both.  However, if they search for committer without searching for analyst, then active record uses `users` as the table name for the join to `committer`.

Comment: I got some insight from suggested answers, which made me realize that adding the SQL would make my question more clear, so I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If everyone of your "Bugs" is related to two users your Bug table needs to be related through two distinct foreign keys:

**Migration**

```
class CreateBug < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bugs do |t|
      # ...
      t.references :analyst_id, index: true, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
      t.references :committer_id, index: true, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
    end
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :analyst, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'analyst_id'
  belongs_to :committer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'committer_id'
end
```

Comment: That is already working for me.  I have the two foreign keys in the table, and the two `belongs_to` statements default to the correct foreign key.  The problem is how to specify the where clause.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding, It is possible what you want on SQL level is to get the condition in the JOIN statement instead of the WHERE statement in order to get the properly filter records?

Comment: I'm saying that when I join on both associations, it uses `committers_bugs` as the table alias for the second join, but when I *only* join on the `committer` association, the table I need to use in the where is `users`.  So *how am I supposed to know which*?

Answer (score 1):

Both, commiter and analyst, are just SQL aliases from the same table. If you use whatever of them on the WHERE statement the result will always be the same. If you want to restrict a condition to a specific JOIN, you must to add that condition to the ON statement.

One option I like to use to do this is adding a lambda to the relation:

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :analyst, -> { where(username: 'Haruki Murakami') }, class_name: 'User'
end
```

This returns

```
SELECT  "bugs".* 
FROM "bugs" 
  INNER JOIN "users" 
    ON "bugs"."user_id" = "users"."id" AND "users"."username" = $1 
LIMIT $2
```

The problem with this is, as long as I have search, you can't pass parameters to this lambda, but you still can do something less pretty but functional like:

```
Bug.joins("LEFT JOIN users ON bugs.user_id = user.id AND users.username = ?", params['committer'])
```

**...which in your example must be implemented as:**

```
relation = Bug

analyst = params['analyst']
if analyst.present?
  relation = relation.joins("LEFT JOIN users A ON bugs.analyst_id = A.id AND A.username = ?", analyst)
end

committer = params['committer']
if committer.present?
  relation = relation.joins("LEFT JOIN users C ON bugs.committer_id = C.id AND C.username= ?", committer)
end
```

And maybe you want to move this code to your model like:

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord

  def self.who_analyses(name)
    Bug.joins("LEFT JOIN users A ON bugs.analyst_id = A.id AND A.username = ?", name)
  end

  def self.who_have_commited(name)
    Bug.joins("LEFT JOIN users C ON bugs.committer_id = C.id AND C.username= ?", name)
  end

end

analyst   = params['analyst']
committer = params['committer']

if analyst.present?
  relation = relation.who_analyses(analyst)
end

if committer.present?
  relation = relation.who_have_commited(committer)
end
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you used `bugs.user_id`, but the `bugs` table does not have a `user_id` foreign key, it has `analyst_id` and `committer_id`.  I want to join on `analyst_id` when searching for the analyst and join on `committer_id` when I am searching for committer, and join on both by joining to the same table twice to search for both.  When both, I need to alias the table name to distinguish which join the condition relates to,

Comment: I edited my questions to add the SQL involved in my problem, to make the question more clear.